# Bash/Awk: How can I run a command using bash or awk

Tags: bash, awk

How can I run a command in bash, read the output it returns and check if there's the text "xyz" in there in order to decide if I run another command or not?

Is it easy?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if COMMAND | grep -q xyz; then
    #do something
fi
```

EDIT: Made it quiet.

Comment: i initially gave this -1 because of the awk tag, but this is also acceptable. +1. EDIT: it won't let me change my vote unless if you edit. But this answer does not deserve a -1, my apologizes.  However, when I did test this I received the output of the grep, which maybe undesirable, but your code did execute in half the time compared to my answer. although, the difference is nominal.

Comment: Using `grep -q xyz` will suppress the output from grep (and also sometimes make it run faster, because it exits as soon as it finds a match).

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
command1 | grep "xyz" >/dev/null 2>&1 && command2
```

- run `command1`
- its output filer with grep
- discard output from the grep
- and if the grep was successful (so found the string)
- execute the command2

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of the command to grep  or grep -e.

Answer (score 0):

While you can accomplish this task many different ways, this is a perfect use for awk.

```
prv cmd | awk '/xyx/ {print "cmd" } ' | bash
```

this is what you want

for example,

i have a text file called temp.txt that only contains 'xyz'

If i run the following command I will exepct the output "found it"

```
$ cat temp.txt | awk '/xyz/ {print "echo found it"}' | bash
> found it
```

so what I am doing is piping the output of my previous command into awk, who is looking for the pattern xyz (/xyz/). awk will print the command, in this case echo found it, and pipe it to bash to execute them. simple one-liner doing what you asked. note you can customize the regex that awk looks for.

Answer (score 0):

Your specification is very loose, but here is an idea to try

```
output="$(cmd args ....)"

case "${output}" in
   *targetText* ) otherCommand args ... ;;
   *target2Text* ) other2Command ... ;;
esac
```

I hope this helps.